# How to get size of the string or any data without object overhead in Python 3

Tags: python, string, object, size

There is getsizeof function from sys module but it includes object overhead.

I already looked at similar questions on stackoverflow but I couldn't find what I'm asking.

```
    with open(args.csvfile) as f:
        for line in f:
            print(sys.getsizeof(line))
```

File itself is 30 bytes and first line is 61 bytes (because of object overhead). Is here a way to just get the size of the data without object overhead?

Comment: Do you want the length of the string? Use `len()` if you want the length of the string.

Comment: "File itself is 30 bytes", I'm assuming you refer to the on-disk size of the file? That one depends also on the encoding. An indicative measure of the size could be `len(f.read().encode('utf-8'))`, but this only tells you how many bytes the file content needs to be encoded (and that's assuming the stored file is encoded in UTF-8, which is not necessarily true).

Comment: @Kevin no I was thinking of size but thanks

Comment: @GPhilo yes that adds up to 28 and 2 left for whatever the rest is probably metadata. Thanks!

Comment: if you need size of file then you have `os.stat(filename).st_size`

Answer (score 1):

```
with open(args.csvfile, 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read()
    print(len(data))  # size in bytes
```

Comment: @Kevin not exactly. This is the length of the *byte* string read from the file, which is effectively the file size. This is different from the *string* length, because strings are encoded.

Comment: It sounds like OP is looking for the number 30 though (28 + 2), though this is just the size of the data, not the actual size on disc.

Comment: If you are looking for the exact match from `dir` command, then this should do it.  Try it and see if it matches in your use case.  My file reads `24,987` from this script, on Windows file properties, and with `dir`.